# How to add check against data within a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

- `$sTable`  = a table of songs (songid, mp3link, artwork, useruploadid etc.)
- `$sTable2` = a table of projects with songs linked to them (projectid, songid, project name etc.)
- `$sTable3` = a table of song ratings (songid, userid, rating)

All this data is output to a `JSON` array and displayed in a table in my application to provide a list of songs, combined with the projects and ratings data.

What I want to be able to do is check to see if the "logged in user" has voted on a particular song so that I can add a class of 'voted' to the parent element of the returned data.

I would lke to do this in the most permance optimal way which I would guess would be to return a boolean value (1 or 0) with 1 being voted and 0 being returned otherwise.

I can then use javascript to apply the class client side.

The 'logged in user id' is stored in my PHP script as $loggedin_ID so I need to simply check this variable against the column 'userid' of $sTable3 for a given songid and return a new column (I would imagine using AS) with a result of 1 if there is a matching entry for that songid and 0 if there is not.

How would I go about modifying my query to add this?

The above are just my thoughts and there may indeed be a far better/more effecient method.  If so please do not hesitate to provide what you think might be a better solution to achieving this functionality.

Below is my current query.  Thanks.

```
$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
           FROM $sTable b 
           LEFT JOIN (
                       SELECT COUNT(*) AS projects_count, a.songs_id
                       FROM $sTable2 a
                       GROUP BY a.songs_id
                      ) bb ON bb.songs_id = b.songsID

           LEFT JOIN (
                       SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating, COUNT(rating) AS ratings_count,c.songid
                       FROM $sTable3 c
                       GROUP BY c.songid
                     ) bbb ON bbb.songid = b.songsID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
select s.songid, s.userid, 
   case when exists 
   ( 
       select songid 
       from sTable3 
       where songid = $songid 
   ) Then 'Voted'
   else
   (
       'Not Voted'
   )
   end
   as 'Voted or Not'
from sTable3 s
where s.userid = $userid
```

Comment: Thanks MGA, this looks like the correct approach but i'm having trouble integrating it into my query without getting alias/syntax errors.  Likely due to my relative inexperience with MySQL.  As much s I hate to ask, would you mind being a little more specific as to how to integrate it with my current query? It would be extremely helpful to a novice like me.

Comment: With a bit more fiddling, I got there... And learned a thing or two in the process.  Many thanks as always MGA.  You're a star. :-)

Comment: @gordyr, I am really sorry, but i can't get actually, Do you want to integrate it into what??? the query you posted into your question i can't understand it but if you would be more specific about it i will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks MGA, it's fine I got it to work.  It just took some playing around with the table aliases and a couple of other minor corrections.  Aside from that, your answer worked beautifully. Thank you. :)